# Open a closed Google form exclusively for a person X

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a Google form connect to a Google sheet that stores all the data from the responders of the Google form.

This Google form is officially closed(past deadline) but I need to open this Google form exclusively for a person X.

Only this person X should be **able to fill the form**, all others should see the **form closed message**.

How can I do this in my already existing Google form?

Answer (score 0):

Google Forms does not include built-in methods to limit form response submission to an specific user. You could create a copy of the form to keep your original form closed for the other respondents, then merge the form response manually, by using a prefilled-form url or programmatically.